# Getting List of issues through JIRA-REST Client in Java

Tags: jira-rest-java-api

I and quite new to JIRA and am working on extracting issue information from JIRA through REST Client.

**Dev Environment**
I am using eclipse IDE and a maven project.

I was able to retrieve issue information one by one using REST Client.
Now I am trying to get all the issues which match a filter and put it in an array.

I went through already raised requests and posts in this forum and atlassian forum. But those are using Searchrequests and searchservice API's which are quite old and replaced with SearchRestClient I assume.
I am aiming to get all issues and put into a list.   If anyone has done it, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got a solution now. However the number of records being retrieved is only 50 whereas manual exection of JQL returns me 550 records.
Any idea how to override default size to get all records.

Code    
 Promise<SearchResult> searchJqlPromise = client.getSearchClient().searchJql(jqlForDataEnrichment);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a better solution

```
Promise<SearchResult> searchJqlPromise = client.getSearchClient().searchJql(Jql, 500, 0,myFields);
```

where
 **JQL** is the search string
**myFields** is the array of fields to be present in result list

Note: Dont put all the fields in the fieldarray, as it may cause timeout issues.

Thanks,
Vishnu

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution now. However the number of records being retrieved is only 50 whereas manual execution of JQL returns me 550 records.
Any idea how to override default size to get all records.

Code

```
Promise<SearchResult> searchJqlPromise = client.getSearchClient().searchJql(jqlForDataEnrichment);
```